# rspec test fails if its not executed first

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec-rails

Following is not very important for my code, but I just want to understand this behaviour. If I run the spec the last test for the destroy action fails with the result `true` of the last expectation instead of `false`. It fails unless the random order of the specs set the destroy spec on top of the specs, then it succeeds.

My spec-file:

```
RSpec.describe ParticipationsController, type: :controller do

  before(:each) { create(:bree) }

  let(:bree) { Project.find_by_slug('bree') }
  let(:contact) { create(:armenia_contact) }
  let(:second_bree) { EcassoFile::File.find_by_reference('bree_02') }
  let(:third_bree) { EcassoFile::File.find_by_reference('bree_03') }
  let(:armenia) { ContactData::Contact.find_by_last_name('Armenia AG') }
  let(:sam) { ContactData::Contact.find_by_last_name('Gamgee') }

  context 'POST #create' do
    login_admin

    it 'should add a participant' do
      post :create, project_id: bree.slug, file_id: second_bree.reference, submit: t('defaults.save'),
        ecasso_file_participation: { part_type: 'client', part_desc_id: 2, contact_id: armenia.id }
      expect(assigns(:file).complete?).to be true
      expect(ContactData::Contact.find(second_bree.clients.first.id).last_name).to eq 'Armenia AG'
    end

    it 'should not add a participant without a contact' do
      post :create, project_id: bree.slug, file_id: second_bree.reference, submit: t('defaults.save'),
        ecasso_file_participation: { part_type: 'client', part_desc_id: 2 }
      expect(assigns(:file).complete?).to be false
      expect(second_bree.clients.first).to be nil
    end
  end

  context 'PUT #update' do
    login_admin

    it 'should update a participant contact' do
      put :update, project_id: bree.slug, file_id: second_bree.reference, id: second_bree.opponents.first.id,
        ecasso_file_participation: { part_type: 'opponent', part_desc_id: 1, contact_id: sam.id }
      expect(ContactData::Contact.find(second_bree.opponents.first.id).last_name).to eq 'Gamgee'
    end

    it 'should update a participant type' do
      put :update, project_id: bree.slug, file_id: second_bree.reference, id: second_bree.opponents.first.id,
        ecasso_file_participation: { part_type: 'client', part_desc_id: 2, contact_id: sam.id }
      expect(ContactData::Contact.find(second_bree.clients.first.id).last_name).to eq 'Gamgee'
    end
  end

  context 'DELETE #destroy' do
    login_admin

    it 'should set the active field to false' do
      expect(third_bree.has_debtor?).to be true
      delete :destroy, project_id: bree.slug, file_id: third_bree.reference, id: third_bree.opponents.first.id
      third_bree.participations.opponent.reload
      expect(third_bree.has_debtor?).to be false
    end
  end
end
```

Here is the controller excerpt:

```
def destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      if @participation.update_attributes(active: false)
        format.html { redirect_to project_file_path(@project.slug, @file.reference),
          success: t('ecasso_files.delete_participation_success') }
      else
        format.html { redirect_to project_file_path(@project.slug, @file.reference),
          error: t('ecasso_files.delete_participation_error') }
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Can someone explain this behaviour?

Additional explanation: the destroy action should not really eliminate the database record, instead of deletion I set an active flag to `false'.

Excerpt of the rails_helper.rb:

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.include Capybara::DSL
  # Factory Girls settings
  config.include FactoryGirl::Syntax::Methods

  config.include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers
  config.include SessionsHelper, type: :controller
  config.extend ControllerMacros, type: :controller
  config.include LoginHelper
  config.include EcassoFilesHelper

  config.infer_spec_type_from_file_location!
  config.filter_rails_from_backtrace!

  config.use_transactional_fixtures = false

  config.before(:suite) do
    DatabaseCleaner.clean_with(:truncation, reset_ids: true)
  end

  config.before(:each) do |example|
    DatabaseCleaner.strategy = example.metadata[:js] ? :truncation : :transaction
    DatabaseCleaner.start
  end

  config.after(:each) do
    DatabaseCleaner.clean
  end
end
```

Comment: change `third_bree.participations.opponent.reload` to `third_bree.reload` maybe?

Comment: the first try was `third_bree.reload`, followed by `third_bree.participations.reload`. It's always the same result. It works, if it is executed first and fails, if one of the other specs is first executed.

Comment: Difficult to answer without more details on the models, but my guess is that the other specs are creating more than one "debtor": when the "destroy test" runs last, you only delete the last added debtor but not the ones created by the previous tests. To quickly check that you can just try to clean the DB at the beginning of the test. You can also look into something like [DatabaseCleaner](https://github.com/DatabaseCleaner/database_cleaner).

Comment: I added an excerpt of my rails_helper.rb